# RegEx in xsd to check anyURI

Tags: xml, regex, xsd

I have a string in xml as

```
<DetailPageURL>http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/redirect?tag=bookmooch-20%26link_code=xm2%26camp=2025%26creative=165953%26path=http://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html%253fASIN=0001714600%2526tag=bookmooch-20%2526lcode=xm2%2526cID=2025%2526ccmID=165953%2526location=/o/ASIN/0001714600%25253FSubscriptionId=1AQVTEDADRW2C3ZDPCG2</DetailPageURL>
```

I want to apply a restriction to this that it should always starts with:

```
http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/redirect?
```

Here's my code:

```
<xsd:schema  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="DetailPageURL">

          <xsd:simpleType>

            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyURI">

              <xsd:pattern value="http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/redirect?[A-Za-z0-9]"/>

            </xsd:restriction>

          </xsd:simpleType>

                </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Its obviously not working because i didn't add =%-_ so on special characters in it. But my question is if i add it in my pattern as:

```
<xsd:pattern value="http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/redirect?[A-Za-z0-9=-_%:/.]"/>
```

Is it gonna work? Is it the right way of doing it?

Comment: `redirect?+` surely wouldn't work as it has two quantifiers in a row. Please try it out yourself rather than just asking "is it gonna work?"

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: sorry that was typo error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
http://www\.amazon\.com/exec/obidos/redirect\?.+
```

ought to be sufficient. As Ian said in the comments, having `anyURI` as the base restriction already takes care of validating the general structure of the URL, so it's enough to validate for the required prefix.

And do remember to escape metacharacters such as `.` and `?`.

Comment: +1. A trailing `.*` would work just as well - the pattern only has to check the prefix, it doesn't have to validate the whole URI since this is already enforced by the type being a restriction of `anyURI`.

Comment: @IanRoberts: Good point. I missed that line. Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Michael Sperberg-McQueen has defined types that match
different flavours of URI in

http://www.w3.org/2011/04/XMLSchema/TypeLibrary-URI-RFC3986.xsd

and

http://www.w3.org/2011/04/XMLSchema/TypeLibrary-IRI-RFC3987.xsd

To see the way these complex regular expressions are constructed, view
these documents at the raw XML level using (for example) curl.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that any legal IRI beginning with the string you specify, and only those, are valid against your type, you will want either

(1) to import the IRI types mentioned in Michael Kay's answer, and then restrict them using the pattern suggested by Matti Virkunen (or a looser one, substituting . for \S).

or

(2) to use a pattern like

`http://www\.amazon\.com/exec/obidos/redirect\?(([A-Za-z0-9\-\._~&#xA0;-&#xD7FF;&#xF900;-&#xFDCF;&#xFDF0;-&#xFFEF;&#x10000;-&#x1FFFD;&#x20000;-&#x2FFFD;&#x30000;-&#x3FFFD;&#x40000;-&#x4FFFD;&#x50000;-&#x5FFFD;&#x60000;-&#x6FFFD;&#x70000;-&#x7FFFD;&#x80000;-&#x8FFFD;&#x90000;-&#x9FFFD;&#xA0000;-&#xAFFFD;&#xB0000;-&#xBFFFD;&#xC0000;-&#xCFFFD;&#xD0000;-&#xDFFFD;&#xE1000;-&#xEFFFD;]|(&#37;[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f])|[!$&amp;'()*+,;=:@])|[&#xE000;-&#xF8FF;&#xF0000;-&#xFFFFD;&#x100000;-&#x10FFFD;/?])*`

This pattern was constructed by manually expanding the definition of the entity `iquery` in the types mentioned by Michael Kay.  It shows that matching the actual grammar of URIs or IRIs is not really all that hard, although sometimes a bit tedious.

It is simpler and less error-prone to import the absolute-URI-3986 or absolute-IRI-3987 types and then restrict them further.